# templating ejs in node for xml

Tags: xml, node.js, ejs

I have a big well-formed xml and I want template it like ejs.

```
<foo>
  <url><%= url %></url>
<foo>
```

but if I do

```
res.render('template.xml', { url: 'http://foo.com' })
```

I am getting

```
Error: Cannot find module 'xml'
```

Can anyone suggest how to deal with it? I need just insert values in already formed xml, I don't want to serialize object to xml by schema.

Comment: Just change extension to `ejs`, and `template.xml` to `template`. Also may be you will need to set a header for xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer from my comment. All template files should have `ejs` extension for express be able to find it, so you need to rename template from `template.xml` to `template.ejs`. Code example will look like:

```
res.render('template', { url: 'http://foo.com' })
```

May be you will need set a HTTP Header for clients:

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/xml');
```